# How do the parentheses impact the 'in' function for checking strings in Python?

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, parentheses

Say I have a Pandas Dataframe with 1 column called contracting_department. It has 3 rows of data:

1. fire dept. development
2. park development
3. police development

I am seeing something weird with the parentheses

Scenario 1:

```
df["contracting_department"] = df["contracting_department"].str.lower()
for i in df.contracting_department:
    if ("fire" or "police") in i : 
        print("IN")
    else:
        print("NOT IN")
```

output:

1. IN
2. NOT IN
3. NOT IN

Obviously this is wrong and should be IN, NOT IN, IN.

Scenario 2:

```
df["contracting_department"] = df["contracting_department"].str.lower()
for i in df.contracting_department:
    if "fire" or "police" in i : 
        print("IN")
    else:
        print("NOT IN")
```

Output2:

1. IN
2. IN
3. IN

Any idea what is happening here?

Comment: `("fire" or "police")` evaluates to just `"fire"`, because it's the first thing that's truthy, and *that's how a boolean-logic short-circuiting `or` works*.

Comment: And `"fire" or "police" in i` *likewise* evaluates to just `"fire"`, so whether `police in i` is true is never tested at all. Think of it as `("fire") or ("police" in i)`; that's **not at all the same** as `("fire" in i) or ("police" in i)`.

Comment: And the `if "fire"` is always true. Strings are always truthy if they're non-empty.

Comment: `if "fire" or "police" in i` is the wrong way to check multiple values.  See https://stackoverflow.com/q/15112125/494134

Comment: @JohnGordon what is the best way to check for multiple values within a string?

Comment: @user_1960_02, the linked duplicates describe that. See the *This question already has answers here:* section up by the top. (Insofar as the OP there gets is using `and` rather than `or`, note that the relevant equivalent to Python's `all` is `any`).

Comment: `if "fire" in i or "police" in i:`

Comment: Or if you have lots of values, `if any(s in i for s in ["fire", "police", ...])`

Answer (score 1):

```
if ("fire" or "police") in i
```

translates to:

```
if "fire" in i
```

since the value of `("fire" or "police")` is `"fire"` (the `or` operator returns the left side if it's truthy, else the right side).

```
if "fire" or "police" in i
```

translates to:

```
if ("fire") or ("police" in i)
```

which is just:

```
if True
```

since `"fire"` is truthy.  It doesn't matter if `"police"` is in `i` since `"fire"` will always make the condition true.